# dropdown not working when directed to another page?

Tags: asp.net, dropdown

I have an e commerce site. It has a view profile, view history and a logout link. On the main page, the dropdown is working (I can choose view profile, history and logout) but when for example I chose view profile (yes, it is being directed), the dropdown seems not to be working. It's just there but has no function? Any idea?

Here is my main page code (where dropdown works)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li id="user" runat="server" class="dropdown" visible="true">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Welcome.." Visible="false"></asp:Label><span class="caret"></span>
                        <%--<asp:Literal ID="ltUser" runat="server" Text="Administrator" /> <span class="caret"></span>--%>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <asp:linkbutton ID="linkViewProfile" runat="server" onclick="link_ViewProfile_Click">[View Profile]</asp:linkbutton>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <asp:linkbutton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" onclick="link_History_Click">[View History]</asp:linkbutton>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <asp:linkbutton ID="linkLogout" runat="server" onclick="link_Logout_Click">[Log Out]</asp:linkbutton>
```

I have the same code for my view profile and view history pages. Any help will be highly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: you have javascript in the main page that attaches event handler[s] to element with `class="dropdown"`, and this javascript is missing in "view profile" page

Comment: didnt notice that. solved it. thank you bro.